# Stop adding extra Closure brackets in JSON file in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing to json file using below code

```
var obj = {
    table: []
};
fs.stat('myjsonfile.json', function(err, stat) {

    if (err == null) {
        fs.readFile('myjsonfile.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                obj.table.push({
                    id: 2,
                    square: 3
                });

                fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4), 'utf8', function(er, result) {
                    if (er) console.log(er);
                });
            }
        });
    } else if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
        obj.table.push({
            id: 1,
            square: 3
        });
        fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', JSON.stringify(obj), 'utf8', function(err1, result) {
            if (err1) {
                console.log('err1');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Some other error: ', err.code);
    }
});
```

but some times some extra closure brackets getting added to it,as below

```
{
   "table":[{id: 0, square:3},{id: 2, square:3},{id: 3, square:4},{id: 4, square:5}]}}]
}
```

Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON.
How to stop adding these closures?

Comment: That's really not something that `JSON.stringify` will do unless something's going really wrong.

Comment: To help us reproduce this, what's the initial state of `obj`?

Comment: In your real code you're actually appending to the file ..?

Comment: @Teemu Not appending because it adds a new array to the object,i'm writing to the existing array.

Comment: @tadman Initially obj is blank.This error is coming after multiple writes(almost after 10 records).

Comment: What I find interesting is that's not valid JSON output, so something is going seriously awry here. In particular that should have, at the absolute least, `{"id":0, "square":3}` and so on. It's like you've injected a raw JavaScript value in there somehow.

Comment: There's this `obj = JSON.parse(data)` part which makes me wonder if that's part of the problem. It's not clear why you do that. It would be better if you *fully closed* the file before rewriting it, or instead wrote to a new name.

Comment: To try and narrow down the problem, if you skip all the writes and just `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` what do you get?

Comment: @tadman Without using JSON.parse how can i push the new data to it.

Comment: You have to parse it, but what I mean is you should close the file after reading *before* writing. I'm not sure it gets closed until that callback finishes. This is where streams can help.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this problem could happen when there are multiple *concurrent* writes to the file. @user123 please show us the complete actual code that does multiple writes.

Comment: @Bergi Yes it sometimes writes concurrently.How to handle concurrent writes here

Comment: Put them in a queue so that you don't do concurrent writes.